# If the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^x f(y) \; dy$ is bounded, must it be continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This question is out of my curiosity, I have finished my calculus course years ago and unfortunately all the knowledge became rusty, right now I cannot deal even with this simple-looking question.

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(y)\ \mathrm{d}y$ exists and $\|F\|_\infty = M$ is bounded ($\int$ denotes the Lebesgue's integral). Must $F$ be continuous?

If not, could someone sketch the counter-example?

Comment: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,x]$ for all appropriate $x$, then $F$ is absolutely continuous.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: I guess the $M$ bound implies that  $|f|$ is integrable?

Comment: @Parsa, Thanks, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsa's comment answers the question:

> If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,x]$ for all appropriate $x$, then $F$ is absolutely continuous.  See [Absolute Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)